# aggregate with FUN = 'c' or 'list' in R

Tags: r, list, concatenation, aggregate-functions, aggregate

Been searching around but with no luck so far.

Here is the data frame.

```
> test = data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), y = c('a','b','c','d','e','f'))
> test
  x y
1 1 a
2 1 b
3 2 c
4 2 d
5 3 e
6 3 f
```

Was looking for a way to aggregate such that y with identical x value with be formed into a list or vector.

Something like

```
  x y
1 1 a,b
2 2 c,d
3 3 e,f
```

Tried 'c' but the result is not what was expected

```
> aggregate(y~x, data = test, FUN = 'c')
  x y.1 y.2
1 1   1   2
2 2   3   4
3 3   5   6
```

'list' seems to work, but it converts character to factor, though.

```
> ss = aggregate(y~x, data = test, FUN = 'list')
> class(ss$y[1][[1]])
[1] "factor"
> ss$y[1]
$`1`
[1] a b
Levels: a b c d e f
```

Any comments is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you understand that the `y`-column started out as a factor vector?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. It's new to me.

Comment: If you wanted the result kept as a list, then just add simply=FALSE to the arguments: `ss = aggregate(y~x, data = test, FUN = 'list', simplify=FALSE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The column 'y' in the 'test' data is a `factor` (mentioned by @BondedDust) as the default setting in `data.frame` call is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`.  So, it is not converting `character` to `factor`.If we are using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` while creating the `data.frame`, the `class` will be `character` and will remain as that.

```
test = data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), y = c('a','b','c','d','e','f'), 
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
res <- aggregate(y~x, data = test, FUN = 'list')
str(res)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ x: num  1 2 3
# $ y:List of 3
# ..$ 1: chr  "a" "b"
# ..$ 2: chr  "c" "d"
# ..$ 3: chr  "e" "f"
```

Instead of creating a `list`, another  approach would be to `paste` the strings together (`toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=', ')`)

```
aggregate(y~x, data = test, FUN = toString)
```

---

Or we can use `data.table` as an alternate approach.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(test)`), grouped by 'x', we `list` the 'y' element.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, list(y=list(y)), by = x]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way with base R

```
res <-lapply(split(test, test$x), function(xx) data.frame(x=unique(xx$x),
   y=paste(xx$y, collapse=", ")))
do.call(rbind, res)
  x    y
1 1 a, b
2 2 c, d
3 3 e, f
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `nest` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

nest(test, y)

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

      x           y
  (dbl)       (chr)
1     1 <S3:factor>
2     2 <S3:factor>
3     3 <S3:factor>
```

These `<S3:factor>` are really lists of what you want:

```
[[1]]
[1] a b
Levels: a b c d e f

[[2]]
[1] c d
Levels: a b c d e f

[[3]]
[1] e f
Levels: a b c d e f
```